# computed property value not updated

Tags: ios, swift2

I defined a computed property `num` in my `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var myArr:[Int]{
      get {
        return [1,2,3]
      }
   } 

   var num: Int{
       get {
         return myArr.count
       }
       set {}
   }

   fun updateState() {
      num--
      // why num is 3 here? why not 2?
      print(num)
   }

   ...
}
```

when I call `updateState()` function, it first `num--` , then print out `num`, but it gives 3 not 2. Why?

Answer (score 2):

You can make your `num` property lazy to make it have an initial value of your array's count and still be able to decrement it like you are expecting.

```
lazy var num: Int = { [unowned self] in
    return self.myArr.count
}()
```

It will have an initial value of whatever the count is of your array during the first time you reference `num`

Comment: see my answer. the behaviour is the same, the syntax is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

`num` will always be 3 because it is a computed property whose value is taken from the length of the literal array. The only way to change `num` In your current code is to change the size of `myArray`.

The `get` method of a computed property is used to determine its value, not just its initial value, so `num--` is effectively meaningless in this context.

So based on your requirement that `num` is initially the size of the array but can then be modified, you will need a stored property to track the current value and a setter method:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var trackingNum:Int?
   var myArr:[Int]{
      get {
        return [1,2,3]
      }
   } 

   var num: Int{
       get {
         if self.trackingNum == nil {
             self.trackingNum=self.myArr.count
         }
         return self.trackingNum
       }
       set {
           self.trackingNum=newValue
       }
   }

   func updateState() {
      num--
      print(num)
   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: How to make my code work with using computed property still?

Comment: Well, what should the value of num be?  Do you want it to be initially 3?  Should decreasing `num` do something to the array?  What are the semantics of the operations on the property?

Comment: I need num to be initially the number of element in that array & I don't want to remove anything from that array but still I want to have `num--` work.

Comment: But why then use a computed property? You are mimicking the behavior of a stored property.

Comment: Exactly.  The whole question doesn't make a lot of sense; either the property is computed or it can be manipulated directly.  The whole thing could be addressed with a stored property and an `init` method.  Even using a literal array doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't implemented the setter. Therefore num always returns the count of the array. Which is always 3.

Comment: how can I implement the setter to make my code work as I expected?

Comment: I can't answer that question because num is the number of elements in the array. Do you like to remove an element from the array when `num--` is executed?

Comment: No, I don't want to remove element from that array.

Comment: In this case, the getter of `num` is wrong. Maybe you should replace the calculated property with a stored property and set it's initial value to the count of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
class C {
    var myArr:[Int]{
        get {
            return [1,2,3]
        }
    }

    lazy var num: Int = self.myArr.count
    func updateState() {
        num--
        print(num)
    }
}

let c = C()
c.updateState()
c.updateState()
c.updateState()
// ... prints
/*
2
1
0
*/
```